# Aplicación web que genere un reporte pdf, y que me filtre los datos por fecha

Tags: html, mysql, jquery, css

estoy intentando generar un reporte pdf, y necesito que al seleccionar una fecha me filtre por fechas, pero no lo estoy consiguiendo, al generar el pdf no me trae los datos.
Los archivos que tengo son los siguientes.

Este es el código del form

```
    <form class="form" role="form" autocomplete="off" th:object="${reportesForm}" th:action="@{/exportarPDF}">
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">Fecha de Recorrida</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" >
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                value="Exportar PDF">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${formErrorMessage}" th:text="${formErrorMessage}">Error Message</div>
</form>
```

Se vería de la siguiente manera
[image: Fecha y boton generar pdf]

Tengo un datapicker para seleccionar la fecha
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el repository

```
@Repository
public interface RecorridaRepository extends CrudRepository<Recorrida, Long> {
    
    
    public List<Recorrida> findByFecha(Date fecha);
    
    public ArrayList<Recorrida> findByNumero(Long numero);
    
    
}
```

Y este es el controlador

```
@Controller
public class ReportesController {
    
    

    @Autowired
    RecorridaService recorridaService;
    
    @Autowired
    RecorridaRepository recorridaRepository;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/reportesForm")
    public String reportesForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("formTab","active");
        return "reportes-form/reportes-view";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/exportarPDF")
    public void exportarListadoDeRecorridaPDF(HttpServletResponse response, Date fecha) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
        String fechaActual = dateFormatter.format(new Date());
        
        String cabecera = "Content-Disposition";
        String valor = "attachment; filename=Recorridas_" + fechaActual + ".pdf";
        
        response.setHeader(cabecera,  valor);
        

        Iterable<Recorrida> recorridas = recorridaRepository.findByFecha(fecha);
        
        RecorridaExporterPDF exporter = new RecorridaExporterPDF(recorridas);
        exporter.exportar(response);
    }
    
    
    }
```

Y al presionar el boton de exportar cuando eligo una fecha que existe en la base de datos no me trae los datos, me genera un pdf vacio.

[image: pdf]

Cuando presiono el botón de ExportarPDF, la fecha se envía con valor NULL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No creo que sea correcto que tengas un form dentro de otro form

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, ya corregí el código, ahora lo que me di cuenta que sucede cuando presiono el botón de ExportarPDF es que la fecha no toma el valor del DataPicker, se envia con el valor NULL como se muestra en la imágen.